# BindingExpression Path Error - How to structure code in MVVM model?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a `Button` that when clicked should adjust the `Widths` of two `Grids`.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <DockPanel   Width="Auto">
            <Button Click="SelectMovie_Click"  DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate >
                        <Image  Source="{Binding image}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <local:UniqueNameBehavior ID="{Binding id}"/>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ShowRightGridCommand}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Button>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
        </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

This `Button` is displayed within a `Grid` as such:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding LeftGridWidth}" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RightGridWidth}" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        // BUTTONS DISPLAYED HERE
        <Grid x:Name="LeftGrid" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" >
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red">
                <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding _movies}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <UniformGrid Columns="5" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Border>
        </Grid>

        <Grid x:Name="RightGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" >
            <DockPanel>
                <StackPanel  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="200">
                    <TextBlock Width="200" Height="50" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} ({1})">
                                <Binding Path = "SelectedMovie.title"/>
                                <Binding Path = "SelectedMovie.year"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="200">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image Source="star_icon.png" Width="100" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedMovie.rating}" Style="{StaticResource AnnotationStyle}" Width="150"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
</Grid>
```

`ViewModel`

```
public List<MediaDetail> _movies { get; set; }
    public string selectedMovieID { get; set; }

    private GridLength _leftGridWidth;
    private GridLength _rightGridWidth;
    private readonly GridLength _defaultRightGridWidth = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Pixel);


    public MoviePanelViewModel()
    {
        ShowRightGridCommand = new DelegateCommand(SwitchRightGridWidth);
        LeftGridWidth = new GridLength(7, GridUnitType.Star);
        RightGridWidth = _defaultRightGridWidth;
    }

    private void SwitchRightGridWidth()
    {
        RightGridWidth = RightGridWidth == _defaultRightGridWidth ? new GridLength(3, GridUnitType.Star) : _defaultRightGridWidth;
    }

    public GridLength LeftGridWidth
    {
        get { return _leftGridWidth; }
        set { _leftGridWidth = value; OnPropertyChanged("LeftGridWidth"); }
    }


    public GridLength RightGridWidth
    {
        get { return _rightGridWidth; }
        set { _rightGridWidth = value; OnPropertyChanged("RightGridWidth"); }
    }

    public ICommand ShowRightGridCommand { get; set; }
```

The problem is that when I run my code, I get the error:

```
BindingExpression path error: 'ShowRightGridCommand' property not found on 'object' ''MediaDetail'
```

I am not sure how to structure my code such that the `Width` properties for the `Grids` can remain in the `ViewModel` but the `Trigger` for my `Button` also works. The `DataContext` for my `View` is the `ViewModel`.

Is there a good way to achieve this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your binding inside a DataTemplate: WPF tries to find the property path `ShowRightGridCommand` on your MediaDetail class, because the ItemsControl sets the data context for each item container it generates to the corresponding item.

What you actually want to do is binding to the view model. You can do this like so:

```
{Binding ElementName=LeftGrid, Path=DataContext.ShowRightGridCommand}
```

`LeftGrid` is an element outside of the ItemsControl. Its DataContext is your `MoviePanelViewModel` instance, and there is your `ShowRightGridCommand` property defined.

A little cleaner would be to put the name `root` on your view's root control (usually a UserControl or Window), and then use `ElementName=root,Path=DataContext....` as your binding - at least that's what I usually do.

An alternative would be to use `RelativeSource={RelativeSource UserControl}`, but I find `ElementName=root` to be simpler.

Comment: Thanks Frank - didn't know about this. I decided to go with the `ElementName=root,Path=DataContext....` way.